# How do I understand this borrowed value error? Building a Vec<&PathBuf>

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

### How do I understand what part of the Borrow Checker it is that I'm violating?

Because Rust's standard library `walk_dir` is [listed as "unstable"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.WalkDir.html)(as of 2015-09-27), I thought I'd try to build my own function to grab all the files in a directory and it's child directories on my own.

Here's what I've got for just listing the files in a directory, not looking at the child directory part yet:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::{Path,PathBuf};

fn get_files(this_path: &Path) -> Vec<&PathBuf>{
    let contents = fs::read_dir(this_path).unwrap();
    let mut output: Vec<&PathBuf> = Vec::new();

    for path in contents {
        let p = path.unwrap().path();
        if fs::metadata(&p).unwrap().is_dir() {
            // dunno, recursively append files to output 
        } else if fs::metadata(&p).unwrap().is_file() {
            output.push(&p)
        }
    }

    return output;
}

fn main() {
    for f in get_files(Path::new(".")) {
        println!("{}", f.display())
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code, I get this error:

```
src/main.rs:58:26: 58:27 error: `p` does not live long enough
src/main.rs:58             output.push(&p)
                                        ^
note: in expansion of for loop expansion
src/main.rs:53:5: 60:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:49:48: 63:2 note: reference must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 49:47...
src/main.rs:49 fn get_files(this_path: &Path) -> Vec<&PathBuf>{
src/main.rs:50     let contents = fs::read_dir(this_path).unwrap();
src/main.rs:51     let mut output: Vec<&PathBuf> = Vec::new();
src/main.rs:52
src/main.rs:53     for path in contents {
src/main.rs:54         let p = path.unwrap().path();
               ...
src/main.rs:54:38: 60:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 54:37
src/main.rs:54         let p = path.unwrap().path();
src/main.rs:55         if fs::metadata(&p).unwrap().is_dir() {
src/main.rs:56             // dunno, recursively append files to output
src/main.rs:57         } else if fs::metadata(&p).unwrap().is_file() {
src/main.rs:58             output.push(&p)
src/main.rs:59         }
               ...
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've got this very loose understanding that one of the cool features of Rust is you have to explicitly declare when objects are supposed to live after the scope of a function.  I think my problem is the `PathBuf` that's created in `let p = path.unwrap().path()` is discarded at the end of the iteration of the for-loop, so the `output` `Vec` is holding a reference to something that's gone.

If that's the case:

#### How do I build up a better intuition for when I'm doing something dumb like this?

#### Is there a better idiomatic way to build up a vector of elements from functions that return resources that have limited lifetimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition here is:

> I can't return a reference to something created inside a function, because it will be deallocated at the end of that function, making the reference invalid.

Instead, you have to move that thing out. Hence `Vec<PathBuf>`, the owned variant of `Vec<&PathBuf>`, (because `PathBuf` is the owned variant of `&PathBuf`) should be your return type instead.

Comment: ohhh, the "owned variant of &PathBuf" being the "PathBuf" ?

Comment: Oops! I think mobile stack overflow edited my <>s out, let me edit

Comment: Cool, so by returning the owned variants, ownership is moved to the caller of my `get_files` which was the intent anyway.  that feels better

Comment: Exactly! This is why Rust is cool, the compiler just saved you from a runtime error with a dangling pointer in another language.